# Parsing S-Expressions in Python

Tags: python, s-expression

Are there any python modules available for parsing and manipulating symbolic expressions in Python similar to how Lisp expressions are evaluated?

Comment: Do you want an s-expression parser that produces Python data structures or an eval facility that evaluates s-expressions as code?

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying- I need to evaluate the s-expressions as code.

Comment: @adinsa When you say "evaluate the s-expressions as code", how do you expect them to be run?  As if they were lisp expressions?  If so, then that would require embedding a lisp interpreter.

Comment: this also exists: https://github.com/jd-boyd/sexpdata/

Comment: https://gist.github.com/pib/240957

Answer (score 12):

[pyparsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/) ([dead link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikispaces) - but see github: [pyparsing](https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing)) comes with an S-expression parser as an example, see [here](http://www.ccp4.ac.uk/dist/checkout/pyparsing-2.0.1/examples/0README.html).

Answer (score 0):

Also, depending on how much work with sexpressions you are doing you might want to check out python hy:  https://github.com/hylang/hy