# R - Parsing Python NLTK Trees via Reticulate

Tags: python, r, parsing, nltk, reticulate

I am trying to make use of Python's NLTK package from within R using the Reticulate package. For the most part, I have been successful.

Now, I would like to perform named entity recognition (i.e. to determine which tokens represent named entities and what type of named entity they represent.) using NLTK's `ne_chunk()` function. My problem is that the function returns an object of the class `nltk.tree.Tree`, which I cannot figure out how to parse in R.

If `ne_chunk()` is fed up to ten token-tag pairs, it will return a result which can be converted into a character using `as.character()`, which can be parsed via regular expression functions (this is just a hack and I am not satisfied with it). Over ten pairs, however, and it will return a shorthand representation of the tree, from which no meaningful data can be extracted using R methods.

Here is a minimally-reproducible example:

```
library(reticulate)
nltk <- import("nltk")

sent_tokenize <- function(text, language = "english") {
  nltk$tokenize$sent_tokenize(text, language)
}
word_tokenize <- function(text, language = "english", preserve_line = FALSE) {
  nltk$tokenize$word_tokenize(text, language, preserve_line)
}
pos_tag <- function(tokens, tagset = NULL, language = "eng") {
  nltk$pos_tag(tokens, tagset, language)
}
ne_chunk <- function(tagged_tokens, binary = FALSE) {
  nltk$ne_chunk(tagged_tokens, binary)
}

text <- "Christopher is having a difficult time parsing NLTK Trees in R."
tokens <- word_tokenize(text)
tagged_tokens <- pos_tag(tokens)
ne_tagged_tokens <- ne_chunk(tagged_tokens)
```

Here is the shorthand that is returned when the text from the previous example is processed:

```
> ne_tagged_tokens
List (11 items)
```

Here are the classes to which `ne_tagged_tokens` belongs:

```
> class(ne_tagged_tokens)
[1] "nltk.tree.Tree"        "python.builtin.list"   "python.builtin.object"
```

I am not interested in suggestions to use alternative, pre-existing R packages.

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the problem lies in `reticulate` not being able to read customized Python objects, which is common, so you have to pass Python objects as close as native Python types between R and Python interfaces.

There's a way to change the output format of `ne_chunks` to string ([bracketed parse format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34395127/stanford-nlp-parse-tree-format)), using `Tree.pformat()`:

```
>>> from nltk import word_tokenize, pos_tag, ne_chunk
>>> sent = "Christopher is having a difficult time parsing NLTK Trees in R."
>>> ne_chunk(pos_tag(word_tokenize(sent)))
Tree('S', [Tree('GPE', [('Christopher', 'NNP')]), ('is', 'VBZ'), ('having', 'VBG'), ('a', 'DT'), ('difficult', 'JJ'), ('time', 'NN'), ('parsing', 'VBG'), Tree('ORGANIZATION', [('NLTK', 'NNP'), ('Trees', 'NNP')]), ('in', 'IN'), Tree('GPE', [('R', 'NNP')]), ('.', '.')])
>>> ne_chunk(pos_tag(word_tokenize(sent))).pformat()
'(S\n  (GPE Christopher/NNP)\n  is/VBZ\n  having/VBG\n  a/DT\n  difficult/JJ\n  time/NN\n  parsing/VBG\n  (ORGANIZATION NLTK/NNP Trees/NNP)\n  in/IN\n  (GPE R/NNP)\n  ./.)'
```

And to read it back in, use `Tree.fromstring()`:

```
>>> tree_str = ne_chunk(pos_tag(word_tokenize(sent))).pformat()
>>> from nltk import Tree
>>> Tree.fromstring(tree_str)
Tree('S', [Tree('GPE', ['Christopher/NNP']), 'is/VBZ', 'having/VBG', 'a/DT', 'difficult/JJ', 'time/NN', 'parsing/VBG', Tree('ORGANIZATION', ['NLTK/NNP', 'Trees/NNP']), 'in/IN', Tree('GPE', ['R/NNP']), './.'])
```

So I would guess doing this in R might work:

```
text <- "Christopher is having a difficult time parsing NLTK Trees in R."
ne_tagged_tokens <- ne_chunk(pos_tag(word_tokenize(tagged_tokens)))$pformat()
print(ne_tagged_tokens)
```

But reading the strings back into R objects shouldn't be possible since it couldn't handle non-native Python Tree objects so the `some_func <- function(...{nltk$some_func(...)})` won't work with `Tree` since it's not a function.

---

If you want to manipulate the output of `ne_chunk` Tree objects into a list of named entities, then you would have to do something like this in Python: [NLTK Named Entity recognition to a Python list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31836058/nltk-named-entity-recognition-to-a-python-list)

Then again, if you are requiring so many functions in Python that you don't really want to recode or use other R libraries, why aren't you writing in Python instead of sticking to R.

Comment: This is a perfect answer, thanks. Just want to note you'd have to use a money sign instead of a period, like so: `ne_chunk(pos_tag(word_tokenize(tagged_tokens)))$pformat()`.